# unresolved link error when working with directx 11

Tags: c++, directx-11

I was attempting to create a class that instances my directx window I have an initialize method and a clean method that I have pushed into a .h and .cpp file and upon doing so I get these 2 errors:

Error   58  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl D3DWindow::CleanD3D(void)" (?CleanD3D@D3DWindow@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function WinMain    C:\Users\thatguy\Documents\game dev\tutorial work\directx 11 tutorial\directx 11 tutorial\main.obj  directx 11 tutorial

Error   59  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void **cdecl D3DWindow::InitD3D(struct HWND** *)" (?InitD3D@D3DWindow@@QEAAXPEAUHWND__@@@Z) referenced in function WinMain   C:\Users\thatguy\Documents\game dev\tutorial work\directx 11 tutorial\directx 11 tutorial\main.obj  directx 11 tutorial

main.cpp:

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include "D3DWindow.h"

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = {0, 0, 800, 600};
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          "WindowClass",
                          "Our First Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          300,
                          300,
                          wr.right - wr.left,
                          wr.bottom - wr.top,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    D3DWindow window;

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    window.InitD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Run game code here
            // ...
            // ...
        }
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    window.CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

D3DWindow.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>

#pragma once
class D3DWindow
{
public:
    D3DWindow(void);
    ~D3DWindow(void);
    void CleanD3D();
    void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);

};
```

D3DWindow.cpp:

```
#include "D3DWindow.h"
#include <windows.h>

// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device *dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context

D3DWindow::D3DWindow(void)
{
}


D3DWindow::~D3DWindow(void)
{
}

// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                    // windowed/full-screen mode

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
                                  D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                  &scd,
                                  &swapchain,
                                  &dev,
                                  NULL,
                                  &devcon);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    // close and release all existing COM objects
    swapchain->Release();
    dev->Release();
    devcon->Release();
}
```

It is in all honesty probably something I overlooked but I'm not really sure why it wouldn't work when it works all under one file.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

```
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
```

should be

```
void D3DWindow::InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
```

same for CleanD3D.

Incidentally there doesn't seem to be a lot of point to your D3DWindow class. Why did you decide to write InitD3D and CleanD3D as part of a class? The way you have written the you could have just written them as global functions.